# How can I run a background process (or "on load process") at asp.net webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I'm buiding a webservice.

This webservice receive request from client, and tranform data to HSM to signature it. But it requires to connect/send-receive data/disconnect to HSM

I don't need to connect to HSM each receive a client requet, I want to open a connection to HSM when webservice run, and then send data to HSM via this TCP connection.

Can I do this with asp.net webservice?

If yes, how can I do??

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `Global.asax` file add an `Application_Start` handler and start the connection there.

Since you could have multiple web service calls on different threads which you seem to be all funneling through a single connection to HSM, you'll need to synchronize use of the HSM connection (use lock).